# Is it a poorly written API if it returns different values for XML and JSON?

Tags: xml, json, api

I'm dealing with an api that returns for XML for some values int or 0 if there is no value - this is how it should be IMHO, but for JSON it returns int or boolean false if there is no value. Does it mean that it's poorly written api or JSON and XML values can differ? I thought it should be always the same and completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that xml and JSON are not the same in there own typing system, so they should not provide the same answer. Stronly typed: 0 is a good answer when item not found (exception should be better) but in loosy typed JSON false is to be preferred. Use the freedom the loosy typed environment gives you. So both api's doesn't have to be completely interchangeable.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If there is a value, it correctly returns for XML and JSON the same number, ie 1556 (it's an integer). But if there is no value to be returned, for XML it returns 0 (integer) but for JSON it returns false (boolean). Most apis I'm dealing with do not have dtd especially this one. But my question is more general - should JSON and XML return 100% same values or not?

Comment: Xml is strongly typed so it can't return an boolean and an integer in the same field. This is not the case for JSON, which is JavaScript and loosy typed. Therefore, the 0 indicating 'no value' is the best a strongly typed language can give you. Like most (array|string)indexof implementations do in strongly typed languages. This is poor design that it rather should throw an exception (via xml) but returning a '0' when a value is not found is an old tradition. Hopefully this answered your question.

Comment: @Andries you should write it as an answer, because it's an answer :-)

Comment: Just realised that -1 is used in stongly typed environment when item is not found.

Comment: Yes -1 or very often 0. When I'm writing my own API I'm always trying to be consistent so I'm always using identical values for both JSON and XML. That's the reason I was a little surprised. Thank you. Would you please edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

XML and JSON have quite different data models and it's very hard for an API to hide these differences completely. However, your question is quite unfair. You are asking people to say that an API is badly designed because it has a particular property, when we have no idea what the design goals or constraints were for the API in question. They might have been trying to make the JSON version compatible with something else that didn't have an XML equivalent, for example.